# Why do I have to enter my response two times for it to register?

Tags: c#

I'm making a hypotenuse calculator in C#, but when the function asking if you want to solve another equation runs, it doesn't proceed unless the response if given twice.

Here's the function that's giving me trouble.

```
void _Again()
       {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to go again? y/n");
            string again = Console.ReadLine();

            string ag = Console.ReadLine();

            if (ag == "y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Going again.");
                _Prompt();
            }

            if (ag == "n")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting.");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            else if (ag != "n" && ag != "y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have not entered a valid response.");
                _Again();
```

I want this to proceed to the next function after entering either 'y' or 'n' just once. I've gotten no error messages so I don't really know what's going on here.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Because you're calling `Console.ReadLine()` twice, and the first input (`again`) is not used.

Comment: remove this : `string again = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: I suggest you to use loops instead of recursive calls if users enters something else than y or n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code simply has two `Console.ReadLine()` statements, and the return value of the first is not used.

That is, change

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to go again? y/n");
string again = Console.ReadLine();
string ag = Console.ReadLine();
```

to

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to go again? y/n");
string ag = Console.ReadLine();
```

and you should be golden.